# Cannot instantiate a StatelessFunctionalComponent that probably returns null

Tags: reactjs, typescript2.0

I have defined a component:

```
interface Role {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

interface BPRolesProps extends React.Props<null> {
  roles: Role[];
}

const BPRoles = ({ roles }: BPRolesProps) => {
  if (!roles.length) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {roles.map(r => <div key={r.name}><span title={r.description}>{r.name}</span></div>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then I try to render it using render:

```
render(<BPRoles />, null);
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
error TS2605: JSX element type 'Element | null' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue related to this problem [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11955).

For now, this trick can be used as a workaround:

```
const BPRoles = ({ roles }: BPRolesProps) => {
  if (!roles.length) {
    return null!; // <= never is assignable to anything, so the return type will be Element
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {roles.map(r => <div key={r.name}><span title={r.description}>{r.name}</span></div>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Stateless pure function components cannot be rendered this way instead you would need a container component that is built using standard React.createClass or using the es6 version and it would render your stateless component and be what is used for the ReactDOM.render method. see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5455

also ReactDOM.render expects a dom element as the second argument. 
`render(<BPRoles />, null);` you need a valid html element as the second argument, you are passing null which React knows isn't a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have used `render` to have a working sample. The problem is that the code is a valid react code but not a valid Typescript one!
I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11955)